# iPhone view navigation - any clever ideas?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that is built starting from a tab bar controller. It's possible for the user to bring up other screens that are loaded with:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextSCreen animated:YES];
```

The user travels several levels deep this way.

Eventually I want to be able to jump back to the original screen. I can't use:

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];`

because it only returns me one level. I haven't been able to use

`[self.navigationController popToViewController:whereIStarted animated:YES];`

because I'm not sure how to get the right value for whereIStarted. Remember this is a specific tab from the tab bar controller.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Tell me if I'm unclear. Farsi is my first language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to get back to the root controller, you can use:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Wow, sorry I missed that somehow.

I don't suppose you know how to then change tabs?

Comment: self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];